# Como soluciono el problema "cannot convert 'double(double)' to 'double' in assignment"?

Tags: c

Programo en Devc++ y tengo el error:

> "cannot convert *'double(double)' to 'double' in assignment"*.

Es una calculadora/proyecto personal pero no se que pasa que no quiere compilar.

También si tienen ideas para mejorar el código con gusto las agregare.

Este es el código:

```
case 10:
printf("\n Escribe el numero: ");
scanf("%lf", &x);
printf("\n Escribe la base: ");
scanf("%lf", &y);   
s=log y(x);
break;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer [ask]. Publicar todo el código de tu proyecto a veces no es buena idea. Si el compilador está fallando en una línea específica, es mejor publicar un trozo de código (el relevante) para entender lo que quieres hacer en ese lugar. Lee también [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en la linea `s=log y(x);` Basta para solucionarlo borrando la `y`. Quedando la linea así: `s=log(x);`

**Código completo:**

```
case 10:
    printf("\n Escribe el numero: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("\n Escribe la base: ");
    scanf("%lf", &y);   
    s = log(x);
    break;
```

**EDIT**

Edito mi respuesta, con la modificación para sacar el logaritmo con diferente base.

**Código:**

```
case 10:
    printf("\n Escribe el numero: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("\n Escribe la base: ");
    scanf("%lf", &y); 
    s = log(x) / log(y);
    break;
```

Espero que sea de utilidad!

Comment: Gracias, pero queria hacer un programa para logaritmos con diferentes bases en los logaritmos y lo mas parecido que encontr fue eso